# Github Actions fails to compile React build during deployment to Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, github-actions

The application I'm working on uses React, NodeJS and Express.
I've successfully setup an Azure Web Apps and connected it to the application repository on Github, so whenever I commit a change it'll be deployed at the same time.

But so far the deployment hasn't been successful.
Whenever the workflow reaches the `npm run build` stage, it always ends the process (exit code 1) and says "Failed to compile".
I understand that it has something to do with the `CI` variable and that I need to change it to `false`, but my attempts have only ended in errors.

Here's what I've tried:

*In React package.json*

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "CI=false react-scripts build",
  },
```

**Error:** *'CI' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

I've also tried adding env in the workflow.yml file

```
      - name: npm install, build
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          env:
            CI: false
```

**Error:** *"The term 'env:' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."*

I just started using Azure about 2 weeks ago, so I'm very much a beginner and would appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the React part, but the `env:` section is indented too deep:

```
      - name: npm install, build
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
        env:
          CI: false
```

Comment: My god, what a dumb mistake I did. Yes, that solved everything! Thank you for the help! :)